# How do I update MySQL from visual studio 2010?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sql-update

I need to update a MySQL database with the new values just collected.

The program will get values like this:

```
sql = "select * from Accounts where username ='" & txtuname.Text & "' and userpassword = '" & txtpass.Text & "'"

Dim credits As String
credits = publictable.Rows(0).Item(5)
credit.Text = "" & credits
```

Then it will update the current value with a new value like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE * Accounts SET credits = '& credit.Text + 10 &' WHERE username = '& Form1.txtuname.Text & '"
```

However, I am stuck on the `UPDATE` string.

Comment: No * after the UPDATE keyword, But, please stop your coding a bit and read about Sql Injection

Comment: still nothing after removing the * , it's not for a website so there will be no need to try and inject my own stuff :D :D

Comment: Have a look at how you have concatenated your strings for the SELECT statement.  Does logic not dictate that you do it the same way for the UPDATE statement?  You have not done so, so why would it work the same way?  Now that I have fixed the code formatting in your question, it's obvious to see where the issue is because of the colouring.  Mind you, VS colours your code too and you didn't pick it up there.  Notice how the control names are red in the second code sniper but not in the first?  There's a reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have to study well about the [update](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) command, since your query syntax is wrong. and you are making some syntactical mistake in the formation of the query. use `Line continuation operators` to make the query more understandable. plan the output before you query.

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Accounts SET " & _
                  "credits = '" & val(credit.Text) + 10 & "'" & _
                  "WHERE username = '" & Form1.txtuname.Text & '"
```

Comment: Works :) thank you for your help.   
        sql = "UPDATE Accounts SET " & _
                "credits = '" & Val(Form1.credit.Text) + 10 & "'" & _
                "WHERE username = '" & Form1.txtuname.Text & "'"